# Good Sketching software

Tags: drawing

Any good Sketching softwares preferably open source freeware?
I basically need it for quickly putting my ideas down into the pc similar with what I would do If I had a pen and a book.
Except that here I would be using a mouse.

Comment: I used Flash before just because its great for drawing with a mouse. Bitch to load and save though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couple of lesser known ones that may suit you:

- [K-Sketch](http://www.k-sketch.org/) which can even animate your sketches. Windows only I think.
- [Denim](http://dub.washington.edu/projects/denim/) which is primarily for web site design, but my prove useful for other things. Windows, Linux/UNIX, Mac.

[image]

And if all else fails, pen, paper and a digital scanner my prove the quickest method.

Comment: Wow! both of them seem to be pretty good! Can't wait to start using them!

Answer (score 2):

I have a Tablet PC and I have been using [ArtRage 2.5](http://www.artrage.com/). I don't think it's open source, but there's a free to use version anyway. The interface is very pleasant, and you can export your paintings/sketches as image files. I was so pleased with the free-to-use starter edition that I eventually bought a full license. This works with computer mice, not just digitizer pens.

Answer (score 1):

[**K-Sketch**](http://www.k-sketch.org/) allows ordinary computer users to create informal animations from sketches.

[image]

(open source freeware)

Answer (score 1):

(For Windows - mainly)

### 2D / Drawing

Microsoft Paint

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/)

[Gimp](http://www.gimp.org)

### 3D

[Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/)

[Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I hate drawing with a mouse, especially for "quick" sketches. They're never as quick as I can do on a sheet of paper.

My solution:

1. Draw on paper
2. Take a photo of the drawing
3. Transfer photo to computer

A phone with email capability works well to combine steps 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

[Dogwaffle](http://www.thebest3d.com/dogwaffle/free/) has a free version.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [balsamiq mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) because I can't draw at all.

Comment: Good program, but for a specific use : designing interface. It's not really a sketching program, as it's restricted to using base shapes for interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try the new PTC Creo 2D Sketch
http://www.ptc.com/products/creo/sketch/download.htm

Or the free 2D DraftSight from Dassault Systems
http://www.3ds.com/products/draftsight/download-draftsight/

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with good old MSPAINT.EXE?

Might help also if you mention what OS you're using (eg win/mac/linux)

Comment: I thought there might be something better out there!

Answer (score 0):

Sketching is a broad term... :) If you need it to draw in 2D, why not try Paint.NET? It's free.

Probably not interested in 3D sketching...? If you are tho, check out Google SketchUp.

Comment: Only 2D sketching. Paint.Net -- I will give it a try.  Google SketchUP --- is it for Desktops or web based?

Comment: It is Desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big set of really sophisiticated online tools available at http://aviary.com/